# Symfony Doctrine DBAL - should we manually close connection

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a controller method where Symfony injects the Doctrine DBAL connection object. I fetch data and return it as JSON. Should we manually close the connection (`$conn->close()`) or the Symfony or Doctrine takes care of it? I have browsed the docs of Symfony and Doctrine DBAL and not a single word was there about releasing database resources. I come from a Java world and this is often an issue in Java.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/getdata", name="getdata")
 */
public function data(Connection $conn)
{
    $data = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM countries LIMIT 5");

    return $this->json([
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Comment: In PHP there is no need to explicitly close database connections.  Each request/response cycle starts fresh and finishes by shutting everything down.  So the connection will end up being closed regardless of what you do or don't do.

Comment: OK, why don't you create an answer so that I can accept it.